# Como fazer liberação função somente quando clicarem na div com botão esquerdo

Tags: php, javascript, html

Atualmente possuo este codigo, ele verifica se teve o clique dentro da DIV e caso tenha ai vai ativar a função "okay". O problema é que essa função é ativada quando ocorre o clique com botão direito ou esquerdo, e queria que ativasse somente quando o clique fosse com o botão esquerdo, e caso o clique fosse com o botão direto, exibir uma mensagem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".iframe").iframeTracker({
            blurCallback: function() {
                console.log("blurCallback!");
                    okay(); 
            }
        }); 
});
```

Se  houver alguma alternativa para esta função em php, eu tbm aceito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É impossível fazer isso pois o evento de click nunca é acionado em um iframe. Ele pode ser "simulado" desta forma:

1. Ele identifica que há um foco.
2. Quando você clica o foco é perdido e como o mouse estava em cima do
   iframe ele faz alguma ação.

Por isso que é `blurCallback` e não `clickCallback` por exemplo. Logo, tanto faz com qual botão você usou, ele apenas identifica a perda de foco. Mas não sabe se isso veio de um click do mouse por exemplo.

**Faça um teste**

Coloque o mouse em cima do iframe e aperte `tab` para você ver o que acontece.

**Uma "solução"** (lê-se gambiarra)

É colocar uma `div` transparente em cima dele (iframe) para "enganar" o usuário, como se estivesse clicando no `iframe`. Veja um exemplo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $(".iframe").mousedown(function(e){
  if(e.button == 2) { 
   alert("Clicou com o direito");
  } else {
   alert("Clicou com o esquerdo");
  }
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iframe" style="position: absolute;width: 300px; height: 300px;">
 MEU IFRAME DE MENTIRA
</div>
<iframe style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

**Ilustração da solução:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, cara

Comment: @RafaelMacedo tranquilo mano! =) Fico feliz em ajudar